# AJAX request to set lookup column from second list

Tags: 2013, custom-form, ajax, sharepoint-on-prem

After making an AJAX request, I have been able to populate fields on a form. 
However I also need to set the value of a look up column to the same value from the second list (LIST A and B both have a lookup column to the same column in List C)

The below code is the lines I am using to set the fields.
Line 1 sets a normal single line field to the correct data however line 2 does not change the lookup (in dropdown format).

I have also double checked that the column internal name is Branch

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl45_g_aecb3c18_b892_4c95_af79_151459af0ea2_ff11_ctl00_ctl00_TextField').value = $(this).attr('jcvr');
document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl45_g_aecb3c18_b892_4c95_af79_151459af0ea2_ff811_ctl00_Lookup').value = $(this).attr('Branch');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically want to load the content of a second list into a HTML Select-Field in your edit form of the first list?

Try to avoid hard code DOM ids. I would prefer using REST and jQuery. And it's better to completely re-build up a select field than trying to alter it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/YOUR_SITE_NAME/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'YOUR_LIST_NAME\')/items';,        
    method: "GET",
    async: true,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(resultsJSN){
        $('#YOUR_SELECT_DOM_ID').empty();
        for(var i = 0; i < resultsJSN.d.results.length; i++) {
            var titleSTR = resultsJSN.d.results[i].Title;
            var idINT = resultsJSN.d.results[i].ID;
            $('#YOUR_SELECT_DOM_ID').append('<option value="' + idINT +'">' + titleSTR + '</option>')
        }
    },
})
```

By the way: $('#yourId') is the same as document.getElementById('yourId')

Comment: Yes however the select-field data comes form a third list. List A is the Form. List B is the user details. List C contains locations. List A and B have the same lookup to List C. Also not sure if this is relevant but the value's (ID's?)  in the select-field start at 78.

Comment: Should also mention that the select-field needs to be ordered in alphabetical order of the text and not by the value.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the IDs start. To order the results simply add the $orderby statment in the url:
*$.ajax({
    url: '/YOUR_SITE_NAME/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'YOUR_LIST_NAME\')/items&$orderby=Title'*
Here you find further information about REST:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx